# How can I resolve the 'Could not find a valid Docker environment' error when using Testcontainers with Quarkus?

Tags: docker, quarkus, testcontainers

I try to use Testcontainers (v1.18.0) for tests in a Quarkus (v2.16.4.Final, java: Amazon Corretto 17) application. When I start it up I get the following stack trace:

```
2023-06-01 13:11:10,326 INFO  [org.tes.uti.ImageNameSubstitutor] (main) Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
2023-06-01 13:11:10,502 INFO  [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (pool-3-thread-1) Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
2023-06-01 13:11:10,599 INFO  [org.tes.doc.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy] (pool-3-thread-1) docker-machine executable was not found on PATH ([C:\Python311\Scripts\, C:\Python311\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem, C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\, C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\, C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin, C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin, C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\, C:\Program Files\PuTTY\, C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk17.0.4_8\bin, C:\Program Files\Java\scripts, C:\Program Files\nodejs\, C:\Program Files\dotnet\, C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin, C:\Program Files\Git\cmd, C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin, , C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin, C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps, C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin, C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin, C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk11.0.16_8\bin, C:\Users\***\.dotnet\tools, C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\scripts, C:\Users\***\.azure-kubelogin, C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps, C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin])
2023-06-01 13:11:10,601 ERROR [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (pool-3-thread-1) Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
    NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception NoClassDefFoundError (com/github/dockerjava/api/command/LoadImageAsyncCmd). Root cause ClassNotFoundException (com.github.dockerjava.api.command.LoadImageAsyncCmd)As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue.
See https://www.testcontainers.org/on_failure.html for more details.

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:625)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:696)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:310)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:286)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:237)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:592)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:640)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$12(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:211)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start Quarkus test resource class com.***.locref.DatabaseResource
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1807)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start Quarkus test resource class com.***.locref.DatabaseResource
    at io.quarkus.test.common.TestResourceManager$TestResourceEntryRunnable.run(TestResourceManager.java:487)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:256)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:247)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:150)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:186)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:104)
    at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:108)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:321)
    at com.***.locref.DatabaseResource.start(DatabaseResource.java:28)
    at io.quarkus.test.common.TestResourceManager$TestResourceEntryRunnable.run(TestResourceManager.java:481)
    ... 4 more
```

I have a class that implements `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager` and starts a `PostgreSQLContainer`. I add it to a Test class annotated with `@QuarkusTest` and `@QuarkusTestResource`.

I used a very similar setup in a plain Java application without any problems. Problems only arise when Quarkus appears in the loop. I researched all exceptions related to the docker runtime and the NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy but was not able to find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried newer versions of Quarkus?

Comment: Solved the issue: Quarkus 2.16.4.Final and Testcontainers 1.17.6 work together fine. I had tried before: 1.15.3, 1.16.0, 1.18.0 and 1.18.2 without success. Resolving the version via quarkus-bom in maven dependencyManagement resulted in 1.17.6 which works as expected.

Comment: @geoand: I have not. Using quarkus-bom in dependency management gave me the compatible Testcontainers version.

Comment: how about you add that as an answer so future readers can easily find it without reading the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The versions of Quarkus and Testcontainers were incompatible. Resolving the version of Testcontainers via quarkus-bom in maven dependencyManagement resulted in 1.17.6 which works as expected.

Comment: see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76391090/2203890

Answer (score 2):

When upgrading Testcontainers in Quarkus, you also need to check the docker-java version. Keeping those versions aligned should not cause any issues.

Quarkus has a comment about it see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/d87ef55647af0a8b6703e3ada5a6da130b139588/bom/application/pom.xml#L209